# Revert married to a non Muslim Man

Tags: hadith, non-muslim

Assalamu Alaikum, I reverted to Islam in Feb. of this year and am Married to a non Muslim man. First of all he is not an idolater nor has he set up partners with Allah. He is a Christian but not by Christian standards, neither he nor I have been raised to believe in the Trinitarian concept. He accepts Muhammad as a Prophet and the Qur'an as scripture, it's just that he has no interest in becoming a Muslim as in praying 5 times a day.We have no children of our and nor will we ever be able to have any. He has at all times been very supportive of choice and has made sure that my needs as a Muslim have been met.When we married we swore to each other in front of witnesses to love, honor and cherish each other til death due us part. These are vows that we have taken very seriously. Now I have read that there were cases in the distant past in which the couple was allowed to remain married and I am wondering if we would be able to as well. I have no one in the area in which I live in to be able to discuss this with. There are no learning centers in fact as far as I know I am the only Muslim in the area. Jazk Allah Khair.

Comment: You need to ask for a formal fatwa from somebody entitled to give you one. You can't base your life (and after-life) on community answers!

Comment: @RubyGunderson "There are no learning centers...". There are websites where you can ask questions to Islamic scholars, such as www.questionsonislam.com or www.islamqa.org. Of course, you can also ask here...but there is no requirement for the answerers here to have a degree or anything in Islamic law.

Comment: This is not a site for seeking Fatwa, we are [not a Muslim peer support group](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/189/islam-se-not-an-muslim-peer-support-group).  See: [We need to set a standard for Fatwa questions](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1422/we-need-to-set-a-standard-for-fatwa-questions)

Comment: This question is a subset of the (Will a (non-muslim) marriage still be valid if the husband or wife reverts to Islam?)[http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1319/3487], therefore answers to that will apply to this as well, therefore I closing it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in the Quran:

> O you who believe! Enter perfectly in Islâm (by obeying all the rules
>   and regulations of the Islâmic religion) and follow not the footsteps
>   of Shaitân (Satan). Verily! He is to you a plain enemy (Al-Baqarah
>   2:208)

Secondly, Eemaan is belief, speech and action and the importance of prayer is highlighted by the below mentioned hadith:

> Jabir (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>
> The Messenger of Allah (PBUH) said, "Between a man and disbelief and
>   paganism is the abandonment of Salat (prayer)."

Thirdly it is not permissible for muslim women to marry a non-muslim man.

> “And do not marry Al-Mushrikaat (idolatresses) till they believe
>   (worship Allaah Alone). And indeed a slave woman who believes is
>   better than a (free) Mushrikah (idolatress), even though she pleases
>   you. And give not (your daughters) in marriage to Al-Mushrikoon till
>   they believe (in Allaah Alone) and verily, a believing slave is better
>   than a (free) Mushrik (idolater), even though he pleases you. Those
>   (Al-Mushrikoon) invite you to the Fire, but Allaah invites (you) to
>   Paradise and forgiveness by His Leave”
>
> [al-Baqarah 2:221]
>
> And Allaah says, stating that the Muslim women are not permissible in
>   marriage for kaafir men (interpretation of the meaning):
>
> “They are not lawful (wives) for the disbelievers nor are the
>   disbelievers lawful (husbands) for them”
>
> [al-Mumtahanah 60:10]

***Point to note here is that legislatively there is no difference between kaafir and mushrik though there is linguistic difference between these terms. Every kaafir is a mushrik and every mushrik is a kaafir.*** [Source: [http://shaikhalbaani.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/is-there-a-difference-between-kufr-disbelief-and-shirk-polytheism/]](http://shaikhalbaani.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/is-there-a-difference-between-kufr-disbelief-and-shirk-polytheism/)

Fourth, it is also worth mentioning is the fact that the uncle of prophet muhammad saws Abu talib also accepted that Prophet Muhammad sallal lahu alaihe wasallam was a prophet and messenger of Allah  - however since he did not convert to islam his abode will be hellfire as informed to us in following hadith:

> Muslim Narrates : Ibn 'Abbas reported: The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Among the
>   inhabitants of the Fire Abu Talib would have the least suffering, and
>   he would be wearing two shoes (of Fire) which would boil his brain.

Answer (score 0):

Marriage between a Muslim and a non-Muslim is normally forbidden according to Islam in order to prevent Muslim from abandoning his/her duties for religion.

> And do not marry polytheistic women until they believe. And a believing slave woman is better than a polytheist, even though she might please you. And do not marry polytheistic men [to your women] until they believe. And a believing slave is better than a polytheist, even though he might please you. Those invite [you] to the Fire, but Allah invites to Paradise and to forgiveness, by His permission. And He makes clear His verses to the people that perhaps they may remember. ([Surat Al-Baqarah 2/221](http://quran.com/2/221))

**But you were not a Muslim by the time you married.** This part is confusing. You should better ask a scholar with good reputation, someone who can answer you with the support of more verses, hadiths and intelligence. Its even better to ask more than 1 scholar. You can ask them by phoning or via e-mail.