# How to marry a woman who converted to Islam, and was formerly married as a Christian but is yet to get a divorce?

Tags: nikah, christianity

Is it possible to get married to a woman who was married before as a Christian? But she has converted on Islam now, but has not yet got a divorce for her Christian marriage. What the process/requirements I might be going through? Is there any way to marry her? I'm a muslim man from bangladesh.

Comment: Islamically, her conversion breaks her marriage to the man she was with before unless he is Muslim.

Comment: the previously method of nikah is Christian base. which no matter in Islam so she is free from his husband who is Christian. if her husband accept the Islam too. then they must do nikah again in Islamic way.

Comment: @YaseenAhmad But practically speaking she still is "married" to that person and would need to be legally divorced in a non Muslim country. Even in an Islamic nation that follows secular law,  the divorce would be legally binding before a subsequent marriage.

Comment: @Ahmed yes you right in the non Muslim country she still married according to that country law.. but in Islamic country she is free in Islamic law. that is matter the law in that country she leaving but in Islam she is free from her christian husband.

Comment: The process and requirements will be part of the national law of the country where you both live and is irrelevant to Islam. According to Islam, on her converting she will wait till the *iddah* to allow for the husband to convert, and will then be separated from her if he doesn't convert, because her marriage to a non-Muslim is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

1) She should be legally divorced by the law of the country, in non-Muslim countries.

2) Then she has to wait for the idda period.

Idda period is three menstrual cycles for menstruating women, for pregnant women the idda is after the baby is born. This idda is important so as to clearly understand lineage if she gets pregnant immediately after marriage.

Reference for idda - https://islamqa.info/en/31

Comment: @ Rebecca J. Stones - i put the reference for idda. Anything more needed? I am new here. I studied Islam, alhamdulillah. I added a small bio yesterday to reduce 'just some random person on the internet' feel, insha'Allah. :)

Answer (score 0):

One may marry a converted women just like he would marry an ordinary muslim woman. There is no verse or hadith which specifically states any different rules for a woman who was previously non muslim.

As far as her Christian husband is concerned, she is no longer his wife under the law of Islam.

Comment: This could us a good deal more explanation. The second paragraph needs a citation of some kind at the least, but it could also use an explanation of how Islam interacts with state laws. **In most countries the behavior described here would be illegal.** Does Islam advocate disregarding the law and going ahead with illegal behavior? Or in such countries would it say you _also_ should to go through the legal formalities?

Comment: Lets take an example of Nazi Germany. Hitler made it legal to kill and discriminate jews and black people. Islam prohibits discrimination based on race. So, in such cases, Islam definitely advocates disregarding law and go ahead with illegal behaviour. However, if the law of the country is in accordance with Islam then Islam prohibits from breaching it.

Comment: In most countries what may appear legal in Islam, be illegal such as Polygamy or What may be illegal in Islam, may be legal such as eating pork. The thing is Islam is not bound to the laws made by countries or governments. Islam advocates what is deemed legal in Quran and Hadith without any regards to consider man made laws.

Comment: "As far as her Christian husband is concerned, she is no longer his wife under the law of Islam. " Is not straight forward end as is stated wrong. This ruling apply for sure only for a Christian whom converted in a Muslim country, else the matter is open and discussed by scholars!

Comment: See for example this answer here https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26384/what-to-do-after-converting-to-islam-while-happily-married-to-a-non-muslim-husba/26385#26385