# I married a non-Muslim, will allah forgive?

Tags: nikah

I was in a very bad place and when I was 20 i decided to not fully do what the quran wants me to anymore. I married out of love a man who is not a muslim. Now we have been married for 2 years and i am getting back in touch with allah but can he forgive me for marrying that man?? What do i do now?

Comment: Also [related](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26384/what-to-do-after-converting-to-islam-while-happily-married-to-a-non-muslim-husba).

Answer (score -1):

GOD said :

> إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يَغْفِرُ أَن يُشْرَكَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرُ مَا دُونَ ذَٰلِكَ لِمَن يَشَاءُ ۚ وَمَن يُشْرِكْ بِاللَّهِ فَقَدِ افْتَرَىٰ إِثْمًا عَظِيمًا - 4:48
>
> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin.

https://quran.com/4/48

This is just my opinion, but I think the fact that you're coming back to Islam, is probably a sign from Allah that he wants you to be guided. So pray to him, he'll forgive you. Inchallah.