# Where the nikah of the daughters of the Prophet held in masjids?

Tags: nikah, prophet-muhammad, sunnah, seerah

Was the nikah of the daughters of Rasool ullah sallalaho alaihi wa Salam held in masjid?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not productive.

Comment: How do we define "productiveness"? I find this question educative and the answers may provide me knowledge I was unaware of.

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) had 4 daughters  Zaynab, Roqiyah, Um-Kalthum and Fatima (may Allah pleased with them) زينب ، ورقية ، وأم كلثوم ، وفاطمة. And they got married in a very early age!

To answer your question:

- As far as i can say after a certain research they didn't get married in a mosque (masjid) as this has never (or at least rarely) been the case AFAIK in the early days of Islam. And as i will mention later most where either married in Jahiliya or before the masjid/mosque was established!
- But maybe we (now) think of Marriage as a social event so maybe the marriage it means the bridegroom asking for the hand of the bride and the father asking him about a mahr etc. (at least what now could be in a contract) has happened in a mosque as the mosque is/was the social center of daily life! In this case this was usual!

Mostly it went the following:

- A man proposed for marriage by asking the father if he would accept him to marry his daughter, the father asked his daughter, when agreement came he announced it, they made a contract or so, after that  the bride was prepared (to be welcomed by her husband) and left (with gifts) the house of her father accompanied by him to go to the house of her husband, where he leaves her after getting sure she was in ease!
- But sometimes it was the father who offered/proposed his daughter to the bridegroom (of course after having her agreement).
- This way was married the daughter of the tabi'i said ibn al Musayib and this way it is narrated (by 'Aisha and Abu Hurraira for Um-Kalthum the daughter of the Messenger of Allah (may be peace be upon him) as you could read in Arabic [here](http://www.alhindy.net/women/great-w/25.htm).

Now to the marriages of the daughters of the Prophet (peace be upon him)

1. **Zaynab** was married in the Jahilya with  أبو العاص بن الربيع بن عبد العزى بن  Abu al'Ass bnu Rabi'a bnu 'Uza bnu 'abdi shams bnu manaf عبد شمس بن عبد مناف he fighted the muslimyn in Badr and was captured after that he sent his wife to her father (peace be upon him) to Medina, and later he went to Medina and converted to Islam and remarried his wife later! She died in year 8 a.H.
2. **Roqiyah** was married twice her first husband was a cousin عتبة بن أبي لهب 'Utba bnu Abi Lahab in the Jahilya (her Father (peace be upon him) was 33 at her marriage) she was less then 10 years old. They divorced after surat al Massad (111) was revealed and then married عثمان بن عفان 'Utman ibn 'afan (may Allah be pleased with him) before the Hijra to Ethiopia.
3. Also **Um-Kalthum** was married first to a cousin عتيبة بن أبي لهب 'Utayba bnu Abi Lahab and divorced for the same reason. And Like her sister she was what we may call under age but the "marriage" has not been consumated as they divorced! And both where divorced because Abu Lahab and his Wife asked their sons to divorce their wives! She was married to عثمان بن عفان 'Utman ibn 'afan (may Allah be pleased with him) in the year 3 a.H.
4. **Fatima** was married to Ali ibn abi Talib علي بن أبي طالب (may Allah be pleased with him) some said before Badr some said 2 years afterwards! She died about 6 months after her Father (peace be upon him) and had with Ali (may Allah be pleased with him) al-Hassan, al-Hussain, Zaynab and Um-Kalthum. By the way Ali afterwards married her sisters daughter

You may find more about their biography in:

[Zaynab](http://www.alsiraj.net/English/albayt/html/page12.html) , [Ruqaya](http://www.alsiraj.net/English/albayt/html/page13.html) or Ruqiyah , 
[Um-Kalthum](http://www.alsiraj.net/English/albayt/html/page14.html) or Um-Kalthom,
[Fatima az-Zahra'](http://www.alsiraj.net/English/albayt/html/page15.html)  (May Allah be pleased with all of them) and on the [Marriage](http://www.shiaweb.org/books/al_nabi/pa14.html) of Fatima az-Zahra' (May Allah be pleased with her)

Here are some Ahadith about their Marriages:

> From a man who heard Ali (may Allah be pleased with him) say: I wanted
>   to propose marriage to the daughter of the Messenger of Allah (pace be
>   upon him), but i tought: I have nothing, so how could it be? Then I
>   remembered how he upheld ties of kinship and his kindness and
>   generosity, so I asked him for his daughter's hand in marriage. He
>   said: "Do you have anything?" I said: No. He said: "Where is the
>   Hutamiyyah shield that I gave you on such and such a day?" I said: I
>   have it. He said: "Then give it to her"
>
> [Musnad al Imam Ahmad]
>
> عن رجل سمع عليا يقول : أردت أن أخطب إلى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم
>   ابنته ، فقلت : ما لي من شيء ، فكيف ؟ ! ثم ذكرت صلته وعائدته فخطبتها
>   إليه ، فقال : هل لك من شيء ؟ قلت : لا . قال : فأين درعك الحطمية التي
>   أعطيتك يوم كذا وكذا ؟ قال : هي عندي . قال : فأعطنيها . قال : فأعطيتها
>   إياه

As the man stays unknown this Hadith is only hassan. By the way most of the Hadith describing the marriage or the preparation of the bride i found had some kind of weaknesses!

> It was narrated that Ibn 'Abbas said: "When Ali, may Allah be pleased
>   with him, married Fatimah, may Allah be pleased with her, the
>   Messenger of Allah said to him: 'Give her something.' He said: 'I do
>   not have anything.' He said: 'Where is your Hutami armor?'"
>
> [Sunan -A-Nisai](http://sunnah.com/nasai/26/181)

And Allah knows it best!‏

Comment: Why do you say "underage"? In Islam, if one reaches puberty, they are allowed to marry, right?

Comment: "underage" as for example our Messenger (peace be upon him) has got marrried at the age of 25 and was 33 when his daughter roqiyah got married!

Comment: But if Roqiyah (RA) was married by the Prophet(SAW) who had yet not attained Prophethood, can it not be concluded that as per the society norms that existed back then she was of marriageable age? Why apply our 20th/21st century rules to the people of the 7th century especially when Islam itself allows marriage on reaching puberty (unless I'm wrong and Islam too sets an age like 18 or 21)?

Comment: @Ahmed in Islam many scholars allow marrying a girl before she reaches the age of puberty, only the consummation of the marriage is not allowed until this age the Qur'an actually seems to confirm this practice. I'm just trying to explain neither offending nor defending this. Maybe now after three years with a bit more fluency in English I'd explain things in other words.

Comment: @MediSaif Thank you for the clarification. Appreciated.