# What was the Meher of Hazrat-Fatimah?

Tags: hadith, mehr, fatima-zahra

As much as I researched, I found some texts (such as: [www.afkarnews.ir](http://www.afkarnews.ir/%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%B4-%D9%85%D8%B0%D9%87%D8%A8%DB%8C-14/399634-%D9%85%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%87%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%87-%D8%AD%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%AA-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%B2%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7)) which indicates that apparently the Meher (dowry) of Hadhrat Fatimah-al-Zahra (as the wife of Imam Ali (a.s.) was a military armor.

I was wandering if it is considered as a true matter? If so, would you please present some related sources? Moreover was it all of her Meher or there were other things as well?

*(Note: please submit your references based on authentic hadiths)*

Comment: May I ask what's the purpose of asking such question?

Comment: Of course dear mate. Thanx for your paying heed to the issue./ The best objective of asking this query can be related to "being aware regarding her Meher (as a great and trusted woman) that can be used as its amount (size) for today's marriage (as a  pattern for youth who intend to get married to notice that it would be Good if their meher is not high ... / Beside of that, i myself would to know about that too. /    God Bless You for paying attention dear mate.

Comment: Oh I see, Jazak Allah kher!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nikah of the daughters of Rasool ullah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25811/nikah-of-the-daughters-of-rasool-ullah)

Comment: @Sassir, although your mentioned question looks to be somewhat similar (and helpful), but, in detailed they are two pretty separated questions, factually, your mentioned question states regarding its place (of marriage) as where was it, but my question is concerning the details/circumstances/deal of its Meher. Anyhow, I appreciate your attention.

Answer (score -1):

As there is no authentic ahadeeth regarding the mehar but mostly it is narrated that hazrat ALI RA had a JIRAH which  he sold to hazrat USMAN RA for 400 hundred dirham ( silver ) which was the mehar of hazrat FATIMA RA which jirah was also returned by hazrat USMAN RA to hazrat ALI RA as a nikah gift

And Allah knows better

Comment: Please take the time to write your posts with proper grammar, punctuation and capitalization. Poorly written posts detract from the professional nature of the site and risk being downvoted and deleted.

Comment: A bowl of watter.