# Where did the -unmarried- daughters of the Prophet (peace be upon him) stay after the death of their mother Khadija (May Allah be pleased with her)?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, reference-request, ahl-ul-bayt

Maybe I have missed somthing in our history so I hope to be remained: I'd like to know what was the home at which the daughters of the Prophet (peace be upon him) like Fatima (May Allah be pleased with her) who was unmarried until she got married to Ali (May Allah be pleased with him) in Medina or Zainab (Zaynab May Allah be pleased with her) who later -after the battle of Badr- left her husband Abu al'Ass ([Nikah of the daughters of Rasool ullah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25811/nikah-of-the-daughters-of-rasool-ullah)) before remarrying him once he converted to Islam.

I suppose that after the death of Khadija, Fatima for example (as the only unmarried daughter at the time) might have lived in the house of her mother. But in Medina did the Prophet (peace be upon him) have a special house/room for his daughters or did they stay with one of his wives? I'd be glad to have an answer with evidences.

Comment: That's better'  () ' :)

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions,

Well it is known that all the wives of Rasulullah salAllahu alayhi wasallam were living in a separate house which were like simple individual room or chambers but separate from each other.

It is mentioned in [this](http://www.muslim-library.com/dl/books/English_The_Daughters_of_the_Prophet.pdf) book that Ayesha may Allah be pleased with her narrated when prophet migrated to madina he left behind his entire family both wives ,myself saudah and his daughters.After settling down in madina he sent Zaid bin Haritha and Abu Rafy with two camels to bring his families to madina.Abu Bakr May Allah be pleased with him also sent two or three camels for this purpose and wrote his son Abdullah to bring his whole family to madina.Eventually both these families migrated together ,This caravan consisted of others besides Fatimah ,Umme kulthum ,Saudah ,Asma bint abu bakr RadiAllahu anhum.

When this caravan reached madina Rasulullah salAllahu alayhi wasallam was busy in constructing the houses for his family near the masjid e nabawi and all his family stayed in those houses.

That shows they were not living altogether but exact could not be confirmed from it.

Allah swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer however it doesn't give me any new information.

Comment: Wa JazakAllah hope may be you could  post some good information here.

Comment: You are expecting too much :) Of course I could do research on the matter but I in first place hoped to get an answer for this question and I'd be glad to read answers from all Muslim sects. Honestly maybe the "any" in my comment is a bit wrong, as indeed you confirmed information I've heard of or already assumed.