# If a wife converts to Islam and her husband or father does not?

Tags: nikah, children

If a wife or daughter converts to Islam, and her husband or father does not, is she still required to be obedient to him?

Comment: her father yes, as long as he's not asking for a sin/disobedience to Allah. If such a person was married, I don't know what her situation would be though.

Comment: Islamically, her husband remaining a Non-Muslim will make her marriage invalid according to probably most scholars; see [this answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/28916/17702) though for differing opinions.