# Pre- conversion marriage

Tags: nikah, conversion

Please explain options. Two non-Muslim people meet while separated from their legal spouses awaiting divorce. There is a sexual relationship and eventually they marry after the other divorces were complete. Years later the husband converts to Islam. What is the status of their marriage and how can it become valid?

Comment: If the husband becomes a Muslim and the wife is among people of the book the marriage is still valid -according to shari'a-! If not please add this information in your post, as it is essential! The opposite situation is covered in my answer on https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/will-a-non-muslim-marriage-still-be-valid-if-the-husband-or-the-wife-reverts-t

Comment: Thank you. She was raised as a (non-practicing Anglican)

Comment: please use the edit link to add additional information.

Comment: Islam SE is not a fatwa site ([off-topic](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here). While questions on the legality of actions (from an Islamic perspective) are welcome, answers may be posted by anybody regardless of knowledge, training or expertise. It is important to judge the evidence provided by each answer to the best of your own abilities and accept such answers at your own risk.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question requires a fatwa. Islam SE is not a fatwa site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will a (non-Muslim) marriage still be valid if the husband or the wife reverts to Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/will-a-non-muslim-marriage-still-be-valid-if-the-husband-or-the-wife-reverts-t)